# Как быстро скачивать и обрабатывать видео на сервер

Tags: php

Так случилось что необходимо загружать видео по прямым ссылкам из других источников.Мы будем получать от людей ссылки и их обрабатывать,скачивая по ним контент.

Основной язык проекта PHP.Интересует,как наиболее эффективно скачивать видео на свой сервер?

1.`system( 'wget http://www.php.ru/mp4.mp4' );`

2.

```
 $handle = fopen($name, 'wb'); 
 fwrite($handle, $file); 
 fclose($handle);
```

3. `file_put_contents ( "filexxx.mp4", file_get_contents ( 'file.mp4' ));`

Размер файла до 500 МБ.

Это лишь некоторые варианты, но как мне кажется они являются адекватными представителями подобных способов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно решать эту задачу только на PHP.

Очередь задач (напр. [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gearman.php)). В неё пихать «задачу» – ссылку на файл в данном случае. А Рабочий процесс - Bash скрипт – постоянно крутится и ждёт поступления новой задачи, и скачивает указанный файл командой `wget` и по окончании выполнения запихивает в базу url, путь, дату-время.

А ваш фронт-енд может раз в секунду ajax'ом интересоваться, загрузился уже файл. или ещё нет.

---

**wget не жрёт память.** Как проверить (идея и код [отсюда](https://serverfault.com/a/638100)). Откройте два терминала на сервер. В одном подготовьте примерно такой bash скрипт и запустите:

```
while true
do
  ps -eo size,command | awk '/wget/&&!/ps.*awk/{print $1, "KB", $2}'
  sleep 5
done
```

Он будет показывать раз в 5 секунд занимаемую процессом wget память. Во втором терминале начните скачивать какой-нибудь большой файл wget'ом. Напр. я взял дистрибутив Debian (3.7Gb):

```
wget http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.3.0/i386/iso-dvd/debian-8.3.0-i386-DVD-1.iso
```

В первом окне у меня стабильно показывалась одна и та же скромная память:

```
./test.sh 
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
428 KB wget
```

Если вы скачиваете в партицию диска-в-памяти, то да, может и жрать память – но не wget, а сам скачиваемый файл.

Comment: Насколько я видел и понял что при скачивании даже wget по bash,то забивается оперативка.Если нет,признаю этот ответ правильнее чем мой и ставлю галочку(оспорьте)

Comment: Где вы видели такую дезинформацию? Обновил ответ после лично проведённого эксперимента.

Comment: `Если вы скачиваете в партицию диска-в-памяти, то да, может и жрать память – но не wget` Я это имел ввиду (не правильно выразился).Это я и наблюдал на своём оборудовании при скачке.Снимаю претензии))

Answer (score 3):

Почти никакой из вариантов не имеет место на жизнь,если у вас нет кучи свободной оперативной памяти и вы не пользуетесь скриптом один.Иначе,вас ждет разочарование через некоторое время в виде падения сервера из-за нехватки оперативной памяти или мощности процессора.

Я решил эту проблему с помощью обычного построчного чтения файла(вес 250 МБ).Единственное,желательно это дело запускать через `exec` или создавать мост-скрипт чтобы он это делал.

Ну,а решение тут взято прямо таки из мануала `php.net`,которое показало себя идеально.Немного допилено,но не суть.Его даже можно оптимизировать.

```
$handle = fopen($url, "r"); // тут и URL откуда собираемся качать
$res_f = fopen('result.mp4', 'a+'); // Файл,куда сохраняем
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
  fwrite($res_f, $buffer); // запись в файл результата
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использую `file_put_contents` для таких целей и вам советую.

Comment: А разве при огромных файлах у скрипта/системы  не забивается память?Ведь очень вероятно что несколько запросов и все полетит или я не  прав?

Comment: @Maksym, если серв не особо мощен и запросов будет уйма, а файлы большие, тогда явно wget